# ZF2 - what is 'use_defaults' key for for?

Tags: zend-framework2

I see reference to 'use_defaults' option in several tutorial on ZF2:
    http://www.qc4blog.com/?p=1391
    https://github.com/blanchonvincent/zf2-lazy-loading-module
    http://www.slideshare.net/mkherlakian/zf2-phpquebec

What exactly is use_defaults key under 'service_manager' key? I was not able to find any mentioning of in in ZF2 code:

```
cd ZF2
grep -ri use_defaults .
```

Documentation also had no reference to 'use_defaults' option.
I'm not sure - maybe this option was removed after beta4?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging and asking on zftalk channel - 'use_defaults' option doesn't seem to be used by anything anymore. So - it's probably been removed after ZF2 beta4 or something - ignore it.